# Eclipse tfs: unignore project is disabled

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops

I accidentally used the TFS plugin to ignore an entire eclipse project (via right click on the project team->ignore)
I can't undo that using the team->unignore option since it's disabled (along with almost every other option).

I tried searching for a solution, but I keep getting results that has to do with .tpignore file - which don't exist anywhere on my computer (I searched).

I tried disconnecting the project from TFS server and reconnecting - didn't solve it.

Answer (score 4):

In your mapped folder at local computer, you will find a file named .tfignore (may be hidden file), then you can open it and delete the ignored path you cared, then save the file and restart the eclipse, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GIT as version control system,in your local machine where you have mapped folder of projects,  you can find .gitignore file which includes all ignored resources. You can remove the unwanted and save this file and restart your eclipse.